# Django / Python oauth2 for facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

Any tips on python oauth2 and facebook.

It seems there are little information since Facebook updated to OAuth2.

Is there anyway the existing Twitter library can be used to suite the facebook authentication?

```
import oauth2 as oauth

# Create your consumer with the proper key/secret.
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="your-twitter-consumer-key", 
    secret="your-twitter-consumer-secret")

# Request token URL for Twitter.
request_token_url = "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

# Create our client.
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

# The OAuth Client request works just like httplib2 for the most part.
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
print resp
print content
```

Answer (score 4):

If your looking for readily available Django apps to integrate with your project, check out the [authentication packages](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/authentication/). Most of them that provide Facebook authentication have been updated to support the OAuth 2 protocol for some time already.

If, on the other hand, you'd like to work with a provider through an OAuth 2 library directly, take a look at [`python-oauth2`](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2)--there's a lengthy example of how you can integrate it with Django's authentication immediately in the README.

Comment: Thanks, I also found the best solution for me to be django-social-auth, we passes all the extra information back to me such as oauth tokens etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome project called [Fandjango](http://fandjango.readthedocs.org) and [Facepy](http://facepy.readthedocs.org). Simply, you don't even have to know or even worry about OAuth protocols anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the user's details or are integrating more of Facebook's graph api, you should have a look at:
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

For a demo of how slick it is:

http://www.fashiolista.com/intro_wide/

Features (Copied from github)

- Access the Facebook API, from:

  - Your website (Using javascript OAuth)
  - Facebook canvas pages (For building facebook applications)
  - Mobile (Or any other flow giving you a valid access token)
- Django User Registration (Convert Facebook user data into a user model)
- Use Facebook data to register a user with your Django app. Facebook connect using the open graph API.
- Facebook FQL access
- OAuth 2.0 compliant
- Includes Open Facebook (stable and tested python client to the graph API)